# Raspberry PI WiFi Direct

Tags: p2p, wifi-direct

I am trying to implement WiFi Direct using raspberry pi and Samsung Galaxy I9300. The raspberry pi of model B is running 3.9.11 kernel with raspbian wheezy image (2013-12-20-wheezy-raspbian.img) and the wifi dongle is Edimax EW7811 un (rt8188cus chipset-rtl8192 driver) . A network is to be set up using the raspberry pi as the group owner , and member stations involving devices with WiFi direct support and WiFi support.

```
The kernel and driver was compiled and the /etc/network/interfaces file was set up to detect wifi network . The user interface app from the realtek website available in the driver package was compiled and installed successfully.

The galaxy phone is made the group owner with the raspberry pi connecting to it using the user interface by setting wps , provision discovery etc. The legacy devices can detect the network as an access point but they fail to connect to it as it asks for an encryption. I have rooted the phone and gone through the configuration files present for WiFi ( /etc/config/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf, /data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf,hostapd.conf) but nothing for psk/password could be located.
```

- I think  the PIN  should be randomly generated by the group owner whenever a request comes to it. Then why is the phone not detecting the legacy device ?
- Is there something like samsung supports only the phones with WiFi direct support? 
  -Is there any way to get the passphrase from the phone?

Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

- When I try to configure the raspberry pi as the group owner using iwpriv commands and using the user interface app provided by Realtek , the devices detect each other but fails at the provision discovery phase and the screen shows started hostapd open  and counts till 120  in the user interface and at times as shown in the figure hangs at P2P listen state. I have enabled dhcp and edited the /etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf .
- Is there some thing like that the raspberry pi can't be made the group owner?
- What is the configuration needed for making raspberry pi the group owner?

For making the raspberry pi as the group owner I set the intent as 15 and make the peer display the pin for wps and start provision discovery phase.

When iw list is given the message displayed  is nl80211 not found, Using the hostapd given by Edimax I have configured it as access point and devices can connect in normal wifi mode.

Initially the raspberry pi was running Raspbian with 3.10.25+ kernel and since the rtl8192cu driver supports kernel versions from 2.6- 3.9. I compiled a new version for the same using gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux.

- Is there some dependency on the kernel version?  Since nl80211 is not supported the p2p commands will fail which I  used to configure the ath9k based devices won't work ( reported in forums ).
- When legacy devices  join the network with rasp as group owner the psk specified in the p2p_hostapd.conf file is enough or not ?
  [image]

Comment: I'm researching this field too, but cannot found any source code. can you provide me your source code that i have a reference for continuing to work  ? Many thanks :)

Comment: I used the realtek driver source code available in their website .Please refer to the link http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=277&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true